# Xamarin Android drawerlayout - adding icons and separator lines

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

I've successfully created a drawerlayout in my Xamarin Android app, but the drawer is currently just a plain black layout which gets populated with items in my array. The drawer item layout looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:background="@drawable/activated_background"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" />
```

I want to to make the drawer more pretty by adding icons and row separators, but i can't work out a way to do it. If i add an ImageView to the axml layout of the drawer item to allow for adding an icon, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewIcon"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I get an error at runtime:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

I'm also confused as to how to add /declare / assign the icons to the string array that i've already declared.

The Main Activity handles the drawerLoyout like this:

```
private MyActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
        private string drawerTitle;
        private string title;

        private Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout drawer;
        private ListView drawerList;
        private static readonly string[] Sections =
        {
            "Scan", "My Offers", "Preferences", "Profile", "Pause Scan"
        };


protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);


            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.NavigationDrawer);


            title = drawerTitle = Title;

            drawer = FindViewById<Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
            drawerList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.left_drawer);


            drawerList.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.DrawerItem, Sections);


            drawerList.ItemClick += (sender, args) => ListItemClicked(args.Position);

            drawer.SetDrawerShadow(Resource.Drawable.drawer_shadow_dark, (int)GravityFlags.Start);


            drawerToggle = new MyActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer,
                Resource.Drawable.ic_drawer_light,
                Resource.String.drawer_open,
                Resource.String.drawer_close);

            //Display the current fragments title and update the options menu
            drawerToggle.DrawerClosed += (o, args) => 
            {
                SupportActionBar.Title = title;
                SupportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            };

            //Display the drawer title and update the options menu
            drawerToggle.DrawerOpened += (o, args) => 
            {
                SupportActionBar.Title = drawerTitle;
                SupportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            };

            //Set the drawer lister to be the toggle.
            drawer.SetDrawerListener(drawerToggle);



            if (savedInstanceState == null)
            {
                ListItemClicked(0);
            }


            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);


        }
```

I've read just about every tutorial going on the subject, but i'm struggling to find how to implement icons and row separators in my Drawer Item Layout without generating a error.

Comment: Drawer is just like a ListView. The way you would populate a pretty listview (creating custom row) is the same way you will populate pretty drawer. Check this link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a DrawerAdapter for your drawerList for that

sorry i was trying to edit

you have to use this constructor for your adapter:

new ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.customview, R.id.textviewid, List);

so try this: drawerList.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.DrawerItem,R.id.textViewName Sections);

Comment: I do, is that not what this is: 

drawerList.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.ItemMenu, Sections);

Comment: new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.ItemMenu,R.id.textViewName, Sections);

Comment: if you still have error you can also create a customadapter extending baseAdapter to achieve this easily

Answer (score 0):

نحوه ایجاد منوی کشویی به وسیله مونو (زامارین و سی شارپ!) برای زبانهایی مثل فارسی و عربی که از راست به چپ هستند:

Making drawer layout from right to left using xamarin.android for languages like Persian and Arabic:

You need to have a .axml file as your ListItem (the row which will be added to the listview), and an adapter, so:

drawerListItem.axml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget28"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="67dp"
android:background="#eeeeee">
<RelativeLayout
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTop1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_background"
        android:layout_height="62dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_background1"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textTop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="asdasd"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and then your adapter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace AtlasAndroidApp
{
public class MenuListAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    Activity context;

    public List<MenuItem> items;

    public MenuListAdapter(Activity context)
        : base()
    {
        this.context = context;

        this.items = new List<MenuItem>() {

          new MenuItem() { Name = "بهنود شرافتی", Img =Resource.Drawable.ic_action_action_store },


          new MenuItem() { Name = "دانش آفرین بی کران", Img = Resource.Drawable.ic_action_action_store },


          new MenuItem() { Name = "خروج", Img = Resource.Drawable.ic_action_action_store }

      };
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return items.Count; }
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = items[position];

        var view = (convertView ??
            context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(
                Resource.Layout.DrawerListItem,
                parent,
                false)) as LinearLayout;

        var menuimg = view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.menuimg) as ImageView;

        var menutxt = view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.menutxt) as TextView;

        menuimg.SetImageResource(item.Img);

        menutxt.SetText(item.Name, TextView.BufferType.Normal);

        menutxt.SetTypeface(ToolsClass.XMYEKAN, Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Normal);

        menutxt.Gravity = GravityFlags.Right;

        menutxt.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.WhiteSmoke);

        ((LinearLayout)view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.drawerlinear2)).SetGravity(GravityFlags.Right);

        return view;
    }
}

public class MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem()
    {

    }

    public MenuItem(string name, int img)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Img = img;
    }


    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Img { get; set; }
}
}
```

and finally you can use this in your presentation layer:

```
 private ListView _drawerList= FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.GroupsActivityLayout_right_drawer);

 _drawerList.Adapter = new MenuListAdapter(this);
```

and your activity layout should be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/GroupsActivityLayout_drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="right">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/GroupsActivityLayout_content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/GroupsActivityLayout_right_drawer"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:background="#191919" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and you'll have a DrawerLayout like this:

[image]